# VM Infrastructure client reporting an error in our HA/DRS Cluster

Tags: vmware-esx, infrastructure

Our VM infrastructure client is reporting that one of the ESX hosts is reporting an error.  The error is:

`"HA agent on esx2 in cluster Ha/DRS Cluster 1 in Datacenter has an error`

Has anyone experienced this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a few possible causes, that's a very generic error. Things like DNS being unavailable to the ESX server is an obvious one, but there's lots of possible issues.

You've not mentioned which version of ESX you're running, but I'd start with this list of [VMware HA troubleshooting questions](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=1001596&sliceId=1&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&dialogID=49940094&stateId=0%200%2050199670).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have a look at the VMkernel logs to find out what's actually going on.  You should find the logs in /var/log on the service console.

Comment: Thanks! I always forget the service console exists on these things.